# JRuby JMX Perm Gen Value

Tags: jruby, jmx

I'm using the JRuby gem jmx to connect to a remote Tomcat server and gather memory usage statistics. While querying Perm Gen, I can return the values for Committed, Init, and Used. Querying Max returns the value 'used'.

Using JConsole, I can see the bean and the byte count for Perm Gen Max. Code snippet:

```
client = JMX.connect(:host => host_name, :port => port)
memory = client['java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Perm Gen']

pg_max = memory.usage.max #returns 'used'
pg_committed = memory.usage.committed #returns the correct value
pg_used = memory.usage.used #returns the correct value
pg_init = memory.usage.init #returns the correct value
```

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, `memory.usage.max` is something like a link to `memory.usage.used`.

You can query `memory.usage.used` directly.

I do this in my scripts.